# on login display a different page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, authentication, login-control

right now when a user logs in, they see specific content on that same page:

```
<asp:LoginView ID="LoginView" runat="server">
    <AnonymousTemplate>
    Please login <br />        
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:qcvalues_testConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [batchinfo]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:Login ID="LoginControl" runat="server" />


    </AnonymousTemplate>
    <LoggedInTemplate>    you are logged in </LoggedInTemplate> ................
```

if i do `Response.Redirect()` to another page let's say `default2.aspx` - how do i ensure that the user does not have access to `default2.aspx` unless they are logged in?

however i would like the user to be directed to a different page when they are logged in.

Comment: @jjd thank you i added a few sentences at the bottom

Comment: @jjd also total beginner where woudl i put response.redirect?

Comment: As soon as a user successfully logs in you can set a boolean session flag like `Session("bnLoggedIn") = True`. Then at the top of other pages you could say `If bnLoggedIn = False Then Response.Redirect("some other page")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LoggedIn` event fired, when user is successfully logged in. e.g.

```
protected void Login1_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("Page.aspx");
}
```

**Edit:** Referring to your comment, if you add the below code under the `<configuration>` section of the web.config, it will make sure, that the `unauthenticated` user will not have access to your page.

```
<location path="FolderNameIfAny/Page.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>               
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

If you want protect your folder from `unauthenticated` users, do so like..

```
 <configuration>
 ......................
 ......................
 <location path="FolderName1">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
                  <allow roles="role1"/>            
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>

 <location path="FolderName2">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
                  <allow roles="role2,role3IfAny"/>         
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
   </configuration>
```

You can allow specific roles to access to specific folder.

Comment: how do i ensure that only logged in users can go to www.mysite.com/page.aspx?

Comment: thank you so much, how do i have multiple folders that are associated with multiple rules. another words role1 has access to folder1 and role2 has access to folder2

Comment: Update my answer again according to your second comment.

Comment: thank you! how do i allow multiple roles for the same location? like this? <allow roles="role1","role2"/>

Comment: did you see what I have added for FolderName2 location ? You can mention the comma seperated roles to specific folder.

Comment: the element system.web has invalid child "location"

Comment: @muhammed can you please help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044919/asp-net-how-do-i-synchronize-users-on-domain-for-windows-authentication

Comment: another qustion for you. how do i add users to the roles? i am unable to do it with the interface

Answer (score 1):

ensure you have an authorisation section in your web.config with `<deny users="?"/>` That prevents unauthenticated users accessing your site.

Forms auth does have a way to redirect to a different page, but i'm not sure how you do it using the login control.