# asp.net - How do I synchronize users on domain for windows authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to do windows authentication on my site because it is only local on our network.

I'm using the website administration tool and selected windows authentication, but when I try to choose users for specific roles it does not give me any users that are on my domain.

My question is how do I synchronize the users on our domain with this tool so that I can give access to specific users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That tool does not allow you to change User information for Domain Accounts.

You need access your domain controller to administer users when using Windows Authentication.

Once you know what roles you want to restrict, you can add something like this to your web.config

```
<authorization>
        <deny roles="SomeDomainRole"/>
</authorization>
```

Comment: @sp i dont need to change user information, i just want to give access to specific users to the website

Comment: you said you wanted to choose users for specific roles, which sounds to me like adding users to roles, which is changing information. To allow certain roles (not change them) add web.config files in any folders you want to restrict and add deny roles="SomeDomainRole" under the authorization tag

Comment: You can allow and deny specific users as well as roles.

Comment: @jeremy how would you deny specific users?

Comment: @sp how would you deny specific users?

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement it with help `LDAP Authentication` , have a look at this MSDN article

[Develop LDAP Authentication Code to Look Up the User in Active Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649227.aspx#secnetht02_step3)

[How to authenticate against the Active Directory by using forms authentication and Visual Basic .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326340)

Comment: for the first link you sent me it does not allow me to use the LOGINVIEW control, it makes me build it from scratch using textboxes and labels

Comment: yah, it should be like, however you can google at your self. The thing is you have to use LDAP Authetication and other things you can check form google.

Comment: how do i get mmc installed on localhost? is this possible or does it need to be installed only on server